Root or window in Python - tkinter?
I'm new in Python and I'm using tkinter to test and learn a few things. I have seen people using root = tk and window = tk
so, I was just wondering which one is the best to use, because those two work almost the same.
thank you in advice and sorry for my English
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('la papu app 2')
root.iconbitmap(default="icon.ico")

text = tk.Text(root, wrap='word', undo=True)
text.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')

menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

///Rest of the code///

root.mainloop()


Both work the same because they are the same - they're just variable names. It's just a matter of convention / preference. You could, for example, use banana = tk.Tk() and that would work just as well (assuming you use it appropriately, e.g. banana.mainloop())
Whatever name you use is just the variable that stores the tk.Tk() instance.
Like I said, it's a matter of convention. And whatever name you use to declare your initial tk.Tk() instance, you'll have to use throughout your application. My advice would just be to pick one that makes sense to you and use it consistently.
